# Never called Lisp function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
   (defun func (in s f l)
      (cond 
       ((null in) (append l (list (list 'end (+ 1 f)))))
       ((eq (car in) 'foo) (foo-asd (cdr in) s f l)) 
       ((atom (car in))(atom-asd in (+ 1 s) (+ 1 f) l))
       ))
```

.

```
(defun atom-asd (in s f l)
  (cond ((eql in nil) ())
    (append l (list (list 'frob s (car in) (+ 1 f))))))
```

.

```
(defun foo-asd (in s f l)
  (cond 
   ((eql in nil) (append l (list (list 'frob s 'myst f))))
   ((func in s f (append l (list (list 'frob s 'myst (+ 1 f))))))
   ((foo-asd (cdr in) s f l))
  ))
```

.
Regarding this code if call `(func '(foo x y) 0 0 ())` the function `foo-asd` will be called, then `func` is called again and it will enter the function `atom-asd`, when `atom-asd` ends it execution, all the program ends, without calling the recursive call `foo-asd`. I need `foo-asd` to be called, but i do not understand why it isn't called after `atom-asd` ends.

Comment: Your `atom-asd` is severely broken.

Answer (score 3):

```
[4]> (trace func)
;; Tracing function func.
(func)
[5]> (trace atom-asd)
;; Tracing function atom-asd.
(atom-asd)
[6]> (trace foo-asd)
;; Tracing function foo-asd.
(foo-asd)
[7]> (func '(foo x y) 0 0 ())
1. Trace: (func '(foo x y) '0 '0 'nil)
2. Trace: (foo-asd '(x y) '0 '0 'nil)
3. Trace: (func '(x y) '0 '0 '((frob 0 myst 1)))
4. Trace: (atom-asd '(x y) '1 '1 '((frob 0 myst 1)))
*** - cond: variable append has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of append.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for append.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
Break 1 [8]>
```

So in `atom-asd`:

```
(defun atom-asd (in s f l)
  (cond
    ((eql in nil)
     ())
    (append
     l (list (list 'frob s (car in) (+ 1 f))))))
```

You have two predicates. one tests `(eql in nil)` which obviously is `nil`, then it checks if the variable `append` has a non `nil` value. Problem is `append` is not a bound variable. It is a binding in the function namespace, but here every term is inclused in one set of parentheses so `append` is by itself th eexpression that gets tested. You might have meant that it should do `(append ...)` when the first term didn't kick in and you should have written it like this:

```
(defun atom-asd (in s f l)
  (cond
    ((eql in nil)
     ())
    (t
     (append l (list (list 'frob s (car in) (+ 1 f)))))))
```

With this version we get a result:

```
[8]> (func '(foo x y) 0 0 ())
5. Trace: (func '(foo x y) '0 '0 'nil)
6. Trace: (foo-asd '(x y) '0 '0 'nil)
7. Trace: (func '(x y) '0 '0 '((frob 0 myst 1)))
8. Trace: (atom-asd '(x y) '1 '1 '((frob 0 myst 1)))
8. Trace: atom-asd ==> ((frob 0 myst 1) (frob 1 x 2))
7. Trace: func ==> ((frob 0 myst 1) (frob 1 x 2))
6. Trace: foo-asd ==> ((frob 0 myst 1) (frob 1 x 2))
5. Trace: func ==> ((frob 0 myst 1) (frob 1 x 2))
((frob 0 myst 1) (frob 1 x 2))
```

Comment: Yes, but `foo-asd`still it isn't called, the result must be `((frob 0 myst 1) (frob 1 x 2) (frob 2 y 3) (frob 3 myst 4))`

Comment: @Aonna You clearly see from the trace that `foo-asd` is called once and the reason is that the `cond` stop at the very first truthy predicate. Thus it finished since `(func in s f (append l (list (list 'frob s 'myst (+ 1 f)))))` returns a non nil value. If you want it to handle both you need to program it like that instead. Just like `if elseif else` it will never do `else` if it hit one if the `if` caluses.